# AWS user-data initial bash script

Tags: amazon-ec2, user-data

I was trying to use `user data` section to initialize EC2 and run some bash scripts on instance startup. Somehow all the scripts are running except the (*) statement. Does anyone know what is happening?

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu
apt-get update -y
apt-get -y install nodejs npm build-essential libssl-dev awscli ruby2.0

curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.0/install.sh > 123
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.25.0/install.sh | bash (*)
```

Comment: Maybe `/bin/bash`?

Comment: ya tried `/bin/bash` too didn't work somehow..

Comment: The error message should be in your console output somewhere. If it's not apparent then try https://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-user-data-output/

Comment: I think this works. thanks!